# Assigning Custom AABB To game objects

Tags: c#

I'm trying to set up custom mathematic code in my Unity project to test for collision using AABB.

So far, I'm pretty sure I have the code just to calculate if two boxes are colliding, but not sure how I'd essentially attach them to a game object to test if they are colliding.

Here's the code I have currently.
The `LineIntersection` and `IntersectingAxis` functions can be ignored I believe, it's just part of my class.

```
public class AABB
    {
        public AABB(Vector3 Min, Vector3 Max)
        {
            MinExtent = Min;
            MaxExtent = Max;
        }

        //This could be a Vector2 if you want to do 2D Bounding Boxes
        Vector3 MinExtent;
        Vector3 MaxExtent;

        public float Top
        {
            get { return MaxExtent.y; }
        }

        public float Bottom
        {
            get { return MinExtent.y; }
        }

        public float Left
        {
            get { return MinExtent.x; }
        }

        public float Right
        {
            get { return MaxExtent.x; }
        }

        public float Front
        {
            get { return MaxExtent.z; }
        }

        public float Back
        {
            get { return MinExtent.z; }
        }

        public static bool Intersects(AABB Box1, AABB Box2)
        {
            return !(Box2.Left > Box1.Right
                || Box2.Right < Box1.Left
                || Box2.Top < Box1.Bottom
                || Box2.Bottom > Box1.Top
                || Box2.Back > Box1.Front
                || Box2.Front < Box1.Back);


        }


    }
```

And in another script called `AABBCollider` I have the following code

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(MatrixController))]
public class AABBCollider : MonoBehaviour {

    private MatrixController MCCache;
    public Vector3 CubeSize = new Vector3(1,1,1);

    public VectorAlgorithm.AABB aabb;
    public VectorAlgorithm.AABB aabb2;
    //public VectorAlgorithm.AABB other;

    public bool Intersect(AABBCollider other)
    {
        return VectorAlgorithm.AABB.Intersects(aabb, other.aabb);
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
       MCCache = GetComponent<MatrixController>();
       //aabb = new VectorAlgorithm.AABB(MCCache.position - CubeSize, MCCache.position + CubeSize);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        aabb = new VectorAlgorithm.AABB(MCCache.position - CubeSize, MCCache.position + CubeSize);
        Debug.Log(VectorAlgorithm.AABB.Intersects(aabb, aabb));
    }
}
```

The AABBCollider Script it attached to my 'PlayerCharacter' and 'Enemy' game objects. All I'm trying to do is print to the console either `true` or `false` if they are colliding or not.
I'm pretty sure aabb is 'attached???' to one game object, so doing (aabb, aabb) just returns true, which I'm not after.
If they collide, print `TRUE` to the console, if they're not colliding, print `FALSE` to the console.

At this stage, I'm not too worried about pushing them apart if they collide, just want to know my function is working.

Comment: what do you mean with AABB? please remove the code which is not needed for explanation

Comment: I'm trying to work out how I can use my functions to print to the console if a collision is true or false. And if I have both AABB Boxes assigned to one object, if so how do I assign AABB to my Player and AABB2 to the enemy. And how to update their position if the cubes move.